# Meaning of потому разве

Tags: словоупотребление

In this comment:

> Наталья, я не выношу пауков. Поэтому я их, да, выношу. Глупо было бы жену просить, так? Остальных я выношу, и **потому разве** что "выпускаю".

Comment: I think you are incorrectly grouping words, should be "(и потому)(разве что)(выпускаю)" = "(and that's why)(I'm only)(letting them go)".

Comment: I thought of that, but I thought he would have used поэтому in that case. Is потому correct?

Comment: Yes, потому is synonym for поэтому. It is mostly used with preceding "а" or "и": "и потому", "а потому".

Comment: And so разве что has the meaning of просто here?

Comment: [Разве что 2.](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/233712): только, лишь, вот разве только. I think просто is also a synonym here.

Comment: I think that разве что should be translated as *rather* in this case: "and that's why / I rather / let them go".

Comment: There's quite funny play of word meanings but the last sentence doesn't look correct to me as native speaker.

Answer (score 3):

```
..потому, разве что, выпускаю
```

Means

```
..that's why, I let them go.
```

"Разве что" is a meaningless idiom in this sentence.

It is usually employed as "unless".

```
Я не люблю колбасу, разве что, когда очень голодный.
```

Comment: Is it meaningless, or does it give the sentence a hint of просто?

Comment: Russian is funny. Wait till you hear something like "Да нет, наверное." Perfectly valid way of saying "probably not."

Comment: The funny thing is that I've heard it and it immediately made sense to me :)

Comment: Upvoting for this answer. @Metaphor should have stress out that commas are missing in the question and they make the sentence sense more clear.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know where have you found the comment, but I can say that the sentence "Остальных я выношу, и потому разве что "выпускаю"" is wrong. So there is no meaning at all.
It is better to say "Наталья, я не терплю пауков, но я их выношу (на улицу). Глупо было бы просить об этом жену, правильно? Я их выношу и выпускаю (на волю)."

P.S. I am not linguistic guy, just a native speaker

P.P.S I have never heard sentence "потому разве" before. The right phrases are "потому что", "разве что" ))

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your input. I think the first part was a play on words, since выносить can mean both "can't stand" and "take out." The rest didn't really make sense to me.

Comment: And what is the meaning of разве что?

Comment: One of the meaning is "except". i.e. "Кино я не смотрю, разве что комедии" — I don't watch any films except comedies.

Comment: The sentence is totally correct and the meaning is obvious, -1

Comment: Anixx, Do you speak Russian fluently? The sentence is very odd and wrong for native speakers. If sentence is correct, give an convincing  answer, please.